# ArgumentException when result is empty

Tags: neo4jclient

With the following query i get a Neo4jclient internal ArgumentException when the result is empty:

```
graphClient.Cypher
            .Match("(a:Application {Id: {pId}})")
            .WithParams(new { pId = request.Id })
            .With("a")
            .OptionalMatch("(a)-[:Uses]->(db:Database)")
            .ReturnDistinct(db => db.As<DatabaseDto>());
```

The result is:

```
Additional information: Neo4j returned a valid response, however Neo4jClient was unable to deserialize into the object structure you supplied.

Include this raw JSON, with any sensitive values replaced with non-sensitive equivalents:


{
  "columns" : [ "db" ],
  "data" : [ [ null ] ]
}


Parameter name: content
  Source=Neo4jClient
  ParamName=content
  StackTrace:
   at Neo4jClient.Serialization.CypherJsonDeserializer`1.Deserialize(String content) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\Serialization\CypherJsonDeserializer.cs:line 61
   at Neo4jClient.GraphClient.<>c__DisplayClass1e`1.<Neo4jClient.IRawGraphClient.ExecuteGetCypherResultsAsync>b__1d(Task`1 responseTask) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\GraphClient.cs:line 820
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
   HResult=-2146233079
   Message=While trying to map some JSON into an object of type ....DatabaseDto, we failed to find an expected property (Id) in the JSON at path data[0][0].
```

The JSON block for this token was:

```
   Source=Neo4jClient
   StackTrace:
        at Neo4jClient.Serialization.CommonDeserializerMethods.Map(DeserializationContext context, Object targetObject, JToken parentJsonToken, IEnumerable`1 typeMappings, Int32 nestingLevel) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\Serialization\CommonDeserializerMethods.cs:line 321
        at Neo4jClient.Serialization.CommonDeserializerMethods.CreateAndMap(DeserializationContext context, Type type, JToken element, IEnumerable`1 typeMappings, Int32 nestingLevel) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\Serialization\CommonDeserializerMethods.cs:line 274
        at Neo4jClient.Serialization.CypherJsonDeserializer`1.<>c__DisplayClass1b.<ParseInSingleColumnMode>b__19(JToken row) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\Serialization\CypherJsonDeserializer.cs:line 175
        at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
        at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
        at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
        at Neo4jClient.Serialization.CypherJsonDeserializer`1.Deserialize(String content) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\Serialization\CypherJsonDeserializer.cs:line 34
   InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
        HResult=-2146233079
        Message=Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.
        Source=Newtonsoft.Json
        StackTrace:
             at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.get_Item(Object key)
             at Neo4jClient.Serialization.CommonDeserializerMethods.Map(DeserializationContext context, Object targetObject, JToken parentJsonToken, IEnumerable`1 typeMappings, Int32 nestingLevel) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\Serialization\CommonDeserializerMethods.cs:line 317
        InnerException:
```

Comment: Which version of Neo4jClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't recreate the exact exception you had here, but I've recreated the scenario and discovered a bug. That's fixed in 1.0.0.654.

https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/commit/25b8d3701a0745fbb577e81005da8254c0d67f6f

Try upgrading. If it works, please mark this answer as accepted. If it doesn't, please do what the exception says and raise the issue at https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/issues?state=open instead of here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the fast fix. It now return a Enumerable with 1 element that is NULL .. wouldn't it be better to return an empty Enumerable ?

Comment: Yes, that might be better, but that would be up to Neo4j itself. As a client library, I don't believe we should be re-writing the responses. You can see in the JSON that there's a single null result, so that's what I'm returning in .NET. If we rewrote that to an empty enumerable, what happens when you actually have a query that returns a single null row, where you expect that as the outcome?